# Confused about this assignment "this.Data1.Table.Rows.Add(this.Data1)"

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Like I said in the title, I'm trying to understand this assignment because I never saw something like this.

The fact is that I have a class which implements some generic types and its defined this way.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T, R>
    where T : DataTable, new()
    where R : DataRow
{
    //some code here...

    protected internal R _entityData1;
    public R Data1
    {
        get { return _entityData1; }
        set { _entityData1 = value; }
    }

    //some other code here. (not relevant)
}
```

Then I have an inherited class defined this way, with a method which exposes the assignment that I mentioned in the title of this question:

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass<SomeOtherClass.InheritedFromDataTable, SomeOtherClass.InheritedFromDataRow>
{
      //some code here...

      public void SomeMethod()
      {
           //here I'm confused
           this.Data1.Table.Rows.Add(this.Data1);
      }

      //more code..
}
```

How can you do this without entering in a loop or something??... or this is because there exist a reference to the `DataTable` object stored outside the `Data` object?

I think that is important to say that what I've shown as a simplified model of the inheritance... in the project involves many other classes which I didn't expose because it would be unreadable.

Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, `this.Data1` is a `SomeOtherClass.InheritedFromDataRow`, which is a `DataRow`.  A `DataRow` has a [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table.aspx) property which refers to the containing `DataTable`.

Comment: I understand... "...which refers to the containing DataTable.". so its the same to do DataTable1.Rows.Add(Data1) if DataTable1 is pointed by Data1 on its Table property, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that _should_ be equivalent.